# React/ Redux - Targeting specific child from mapped array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following array of teams that are being mapped out into Team components:

**parent.js**

```
render() {
    let teamArray = this.props.teamsReducer.teams;
    <ul>
        {teamArray.map((team) => {
            <Team key={team._id} />
        })}
    </ul>
}
```

**Team.js**

```
render() {
    let getTeamDetailsAnimation = this.props.teamReducer.getTeamDetailsAnimation;

    return (
        <li className='indent'>
            <span className={"cta " + getTeamDetailsAnimation} onClick={() => {this.chooseTeam(team._id,team.name)}}>Select</span>
        </li>
    )
}
```

`getTeamDetailsAnimation` basically gets updated from being an empty string to 'active' which in turn shows a loading spinner while an AJAX request is made. Once the AJAX request is finished `getTeamDetailsAnimation` gets updated back to an empty string and hence the loading spinner is removed.

The issue i'm having trouble understanding how to tackle is how to apply the `getTeamDetailsAnimation` to the relevant Team component that was clicked. At the moment seeing as every Team component that is rendered has that part of the teamReducer applied to it, when I click one and an ajax request is made to get the team details then all the Team components show the loading spinner.

I thought about just doing a setState within that Team component to keep the state local to that component but the issue here is my `chooseTeam` function dispatches an action that lives in a Thunk to make the Ajax request and I need to be able to update the state only when the request is complete which is not local to that component.

As i've setup patterns to keep all my AJAX requests external to my components I want to try and keep it that way, is it possible to keep this AJAX request external to the component given i'm only try to target the relevant component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the loading state for individual teams, rather than as a whole

The structure of you `teamReducer` must be something like

```
const initialState = [
   {
       getTeamDetailsAnimation: '',
       // other properties
   }
]
```

For simplicity, you can pass the index of the team to get its loading state

**Parent:**

```
render() {
    let teamArray = this.props.teamsReducer.teams;
    <ul>
        {teamArray.map((team, index) => {
            <Team key={team._id} index={index}/>
        })}
    </ul>
}
```

**Team:**

```
render() {
    let getTeamDetailsAnimation = this.props.teamReducer[this.props.index].getTeamDetailsAnimation;

    return (
        <li className='indent'>
            <span className={"cta " + getTeamDetailsAnimation} onClick={() => {this.chooseTeam(team._id,team.name)}}>Select</span>
        </li>
    )
}
```